# Simple clojure program doesn't work

Tags: clojure, lighttable

I am trying to follow the example in Clojure Data Analasys Cookbook. I am using LightTable to play with the program. The first example shows how to read in .csv data.

I used lein new getting-data. I then added the two dependencies to the project file

```
  (defproject getting-data "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [
                  [org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                  [incanter/incanter-core "1.4.1"]
                  [incanter/incanter-io "1.4.1"]
                ]
  )
```

Then in the core.clj file I say as below, using cmd-shift-enter in LightTable to evaluate the program, but I get those exceptions:

```
(use 'incanter.core 'incanter.io)
```

clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: use in this context, compiling:(/Users/idf/Documents/clojure/getting-data/src/getting_data/core.clj:1:1)

```
(read-dataset "data/small-sample.csv")
```

clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: read-dataset in this context, compiling:(/Users/idf/Documents/clojure/getting-data/src/getting_data/core.clj:4:1)

Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show your entire project.clj?

Comment: Just edited the post.

Comment: How are you evaluating/compiling the expressions?

Comment: Your project.clj looks fine btw.

Comment: See the rewrite above. I am using LightTable, using cmd-shift-enter

Comment: I'm not sure then, since I haven't used LT much. But you need to have a proper namespace declaration anyway, like this:

Comment: (ns getting-date.core
  (:require [incanter.core :as incanter])
  (:require [incanter.io :as io]))

Comment: The problem seems to be [incanter/incanter-core "1.5.4"] [incanter/incanter-io "1.5.4"]

Comment: Have you put `(use ...)` in your `(ns ...)` instead of `(:use ...)` (note the colon).

Comment: Please post your core.clj ns declaration.

Comment: You might want to try running it at a prompt with `lein repl`.  That will tell you whether it's something about the LightTable configuration.  (I know nothing about LT, though.)

Comment: As I stated the problem is that I needed to use 1.5.4. not sure why the original does not work.

Answer (score 2):

"Unable to resolve symbol: use in this context" means that the light table environment is unable to evaluate basically anything: nothing incanter-related can be the problem. Not using light table, I can't offer further advice on fixing it, but it looks like you've somehow wandered into a namespace that doesn't have `clojure.core` referred. It should work if you `(clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core)` before the rest of the code you actually want to run, but of course that's not supposed to be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

put your code

```
(ns getting-data.core)
(use 'incanter.core 'incanter.io)
(read-dataset "data/small-sample.csv")
```

in the generated core.clj file move there and press strg-enter. Now it should evaluate everything inside the editor. Alternatively open the project and open an Instarepl and LightTable should ask you into which project the repl should hook into.

regards
fricke